# MultiDim Array Sort query

Tags: php

I use this to sort a multidimensional array

```
    usort($items, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['item'] - $b['item'];
    });
```

**BEFORE SORT**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 3199d45c-a5c2-474c-8768-06e18fdf6ace
        [status] => active
        [item] => Spar
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 4001
        [status] => active
        [item] => Starbucks
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 4002
        [status] => active
        [item] => Burger King
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 4003
        [status] => active
        [item] => Steers
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 4004
        [status] => active
        [item] => Hungry Lion
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 658bee38-04c2-4f27-812f-dd46c3652dcb
        [status] => active
        [item] => Deslies
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => a5c2b1dc-584d-4175-9d21-e7a910606835
        [status] => active
        [item] => Nandos
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => e1a14e51-0cfc-47c6-8ae8-d408fd43571e
        [status] => active
        [item] => OK
    )

)
```

**AFTER SORT**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 658bee38-04c2-4f27-812f-dd46c3652dcb
        [status] => active
        [item] => Deslies
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => a5c2b1dc-584d-4175-9d21-e7a910606835
        [status] => active
        [item] => Nandos
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => e1a14e51-0cfc-47c6-8ae8-d408fd43571e
        [status] => active
        [item] => OK
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 4004
        [status] => active
        [item] => Hungry Lion
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 4003
        [status] => active
        [item] => Steers
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 4001
        [status] => active
        [item] => Starbucks
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 4002
        [status] => active
        [item] => Burger King
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [uuid] => 3199d45c-a5c2-474c-8768-06e18fdf6ace
        [status] => active
        [item] => Spar
    )

)
```

Why Does `Burger King` not sit first after sort?

Comment: Why does Hungry Lion sit after OK and before Steers? :)

Comment: what is item ? string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare them and then return the result based on the 'item' you have ..

For example :

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["item"], $b["item"]);
}

usort($items, "compare");

while (list($key, $value) = each($items)) {
    echo "\$items[$key]: " . $value["item"] . "\n";
}
```

There are examples of this here : [READ THE MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 1):

The callback function you're using is used to compare integers, not strings
To compare strings instead of integers, use strcmp() instead of directly subtracting two strings.

```
usort($items, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['item'], $b['item']);
});
```